# Excel VBA Vlookup - Unable to Get the Vlookup Property

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the following script and I'm getting a VLOOKUP error:

```
Dim DataRange, LookupRange As Range
Dim Data, Test As Variant

Set DataRange = Sheets("sheet").Range("A1:K12000")
Set LookupRange = sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C50")
Data = DataRange.Value

For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data,1)
  ReDim Preserve Test(1 To 3, 1 To i)
  test(1, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Data(i, 4), LookupRange, 3, 0)
  'Other stuff works fine
Next i
```

Unfortunately, I get the error stating:

```
"Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"
```

This is strange because all of the variables and ranges look fine in watch mode.  The lookup is also alphabetic... Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Is the value in the lookup table?  Try dropping the `Worksheetfunction` and checking the reurn value with `IsError()`: that approach doesn't cause a run-time error if the value is not found.

Comment: How does `test(i)` work after you define the array to be 2-D?

Comment: @enderland Sorry, I just typed it wrong when I was simplifying the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can mean any number of things. It may simply mean your `Data(i, 4)` value is not found in LookupRange.

```
Run-time error '1004':

Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class
```

is equivilent to getting `#N/A` From `=vlookup("A",A1:B3,2,false)`

Set a breakpoint on the line

```
test(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Data(i, 4), LookupRange, 3, 0)
```

and set a watch on `Data(i, 4)` as well as a watch on `i`. See if the value in `Data(i, 4)` exists in your lookup range. See if `i` is greater than 1, if it has run some iterations of the loop correctly.

As a side note your code wont run anyway since `Test` is an empty variant not an array. You need a line like

```
ReDim Test(LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1))
```

before the for loop for it to work.

Read up on error handling [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm). You'll need that to handle VLOOKUP correctly from VBA.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure out what was happening.  It turned out there was a missing value in the output I receive.  I was able to fix it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error, it means that the value you are using in the first slot of the `VLookup()` method, in this case the `Data(i,4)`, is not able to be found in the `LookupRange` you are using in order to return anything.

Before doing the `VLookup`, test if the value you want to do the lookup with actually exists in your range, first - which you don't need to set in a variable, just loop through it on the fly. You can use `.Find` to do your search, and then you should be limiting your datasource to a single column, to look at your columns on your other sheet, which I wasn't sure if it was on this workbook or another workbook - for me, when I was doing it, it was on another one, so I named it that way, but you're just going to use whatever workbook has your `sheet2`:

```
Dim LookupRange, r As Range
Dim LookupValue As String
Dim lastRow, ctr As Integer
ctr = 1
lastRow = YourWb.Sheets("sheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set LookupRange = AnotherWb.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C50")

For Each Cell In YourWb.Sheets("sheet").Range("M2:M" & lastRow)  

    ' For me, the M column was where my VLOOKUPs were going
    ' Get your lookup value here by using the column it is in and the counter
    LookupValue = YourWb.Sheets("sheet").Range("A" & ctr).Value ' just use one column with your values, not A:K, here

    With LookupRange
        Set r = .Find(LookupValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                LookupValue, LookupRange, 16, False)
        End If
    End With
    ctr = ctr + 1

Next
```

For me, I was just assigning the `VLookup` value directly to the column of cells - there was no need to use a `Variant` or `Array`. Why would you? Just write it all back out to the column directly.

It's also where I'm not keen on the whole `For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data,1)` line, anyway. You can either use the method of appending a counter or do a `For Each Cell in ...` your range of cells. I demonstrated both methods, above.